# Break in loop using each_with_index and pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a loop of comments I'm trying to add a break after the first 3 using 'each_with_index' like so:

```
<% @comments.each_with_index  do |question, i| %>
<% if i == 2 %>
  This is a break
<% end %>
  <%= @comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is I'm using the will_paginate gem to paginate the comments 3 per page. This means that the break is repeated every 3 comments since 'i' is reset every page. Is there a work around this or another way to find the third comment?

Comment: question is not clear to me.

Comment: The break that I want only showing up once (after the third comment) repeats after every third comment instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using will_paginate's current_page method so that the break will only show on the first page.

```
<% @comments.each_with_index  do |question, i| %>    
<% if @comments.current_page == 1 && i == 2 %>
 Break
<% end %>
 <%= @comment.body %>    
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the ideal solution, but you could render a "break" for each element and use css' nth-child selector to only reveal the third one.

```
.break {
    display: none;
}

div:nth-child(3) .break {
    display: block;
}

<div>1<span class="break">break</span></div>
<div>2<span class="break">break</span></div>
<div>3<span class="break">break</span></div> <!-- only this .break will be shown -->
<div>4<span class="break">break</span></div>
<div>5<span class="break">break</span></div>
<div>6<span class="break">break</span></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q9yhps2c/)

Another option would be to use a flag in the outer scope to prevent the "break" from being rendered multiple times. (The following has not been tested.)

```
<%- render_break = true %>

<% @comments.each_with_index  do |question, i| %>
  <% if render_break && i == 2 %>
    This is a break
    <%- render_break = false %>
  <% end %>
  <%= @comment.body %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It seems using a flag causes the same problem. It resets render_break back to true after 3 comments. I'm not so sure about using css to hide the break since the the break is a fair-sized partial itself and I fear that will slow down rendering the comments.